# How to change sites-available configurations in NGinx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I am new to Linux. I want to deploy my asp.net core application on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS virtual machine. I installed asp.net core on Ubuntu and managed to run a simple asp.net core web application on Ubuntu.
In addition, I want to setup Nginx web server as the reverse proxy for my application. I followed [this](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/linuxproduction.html) article in order to install Nginx. Eventhough Nginx server successfully installed I cannot change following configurations on default file of Nginx Sites-Available section as above article explained since the whole directory is read only.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

[image]

What have I done wrong and please tell me how to edit this file.

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User,

Answer (score 1):

The directory is owned by root, so you need to login as root or use `su` or `sudo` to get root rights in order to modify its contents.

Comment: I did the same but still not working

Comment: What exactle is "did the same"?